# Canvas leaves an "imprint" outside when arcs near the edge enlarged

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

This is hard to explain in words, rather I uploaded the site [here](http://design.gwiki.io) to demonstrate the problem. There's a snippet below that has the code and simulates the same problem.

Notice how when you scroll down, and hover near the edge, white imprints are left outside the canvas on neighbouring divs. Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var mouse = {
 x: undefined,
 y: undefined
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
 mouse.x = event.x;
 mouse.y = event.y;
});

function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius, bg){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.dx = dx;
 this.dy = dy;
 this.radius = radius;
 this.defaultRadius = radius;
 this.bg = bg;

 this.draw = function(){
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  context.fillStyle = this.bg;
  context.fill();
 }

 this.update = function(){
  if (this.x + this.radius > innerWidth || this.x - this.radius < 0) {
   this.dx = -this.dx;
  }

  if (this.y + this.radius > innerHeight || this.y - this.radius < 0) {
   this.dy = -this.dy;
  }

  if (this.x - mouse.x < 50 && this.x - mouse.x > -50 && this.y - mouse.y < 50 && this.y - mouse.y > -50) {
   if (this.radius < 30) {
    this.radius += 5;
   }
  } else {
   if (this.radius > this.defaultRadius) {
    this.radius -= 1;
   }
  }

  this.x += this.dx;
  this.y += this.dy;
  
  this.draw();
 }
}

var circlesArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
 addNewCircle();
}

function addNewCircle(){
 var radius = (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
 var x = (Math.random() * (innerWidth - (radius*2))) + radius;
 var y = (Math.random() * (innerHeight - (radius*2))) + radius;
 var dx = Math.random() - 0.5;
 var dy = Math.random() - 0.5;
 var bg = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)';

 circlesArray.push(new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius, bg));
}

function animate(){
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 context.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

 for(var i = 0; i < circlesArray.length; i++){
  circlesArray[i].update();
 }
}

animate();
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
}

#page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#page canvas{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#top-bar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  
  <div id="top-bar">
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you defining `innerWidth` and `innerHeight`? It appears you are drawing in places you are not clearing.

Comment: `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` seem to work without the `window` prefix, but you're correct, I changed the canvas' width and height properties but forgot to update the clearRect method.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot those are `window` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your canvas is setting height based on body, but your #top-bar div is taking up some of that space.

So that extra space is where you #top-bar div is

You could set the canvas size to be (body - #top-bar height).